# Unable to Import "fscalendar.h" in bridge file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, fscalendar

My project is iOS Ver 11.0 and Xcode 9.4. My project already has a Bridging file and it contains one objective C framework. It works perfectly.

But when I import "FSCalendar.h" in Bridge file. I got an error "FSCalendar.h file not found"

Comment: did you try import < FSCalendar/FSCalendar.h>

Comment: Thanks, bro. I forget that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try importing something like below.

```
#import < FSCalendar/FSCalendar.h>
```